# Automatically start postfix on Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard

Tags: mac-osx, postfix

Hey guys, I'm doing a lot of test emailing for a PHP based application. I find that sometimes my emails become 'stuck'.

I did find a solution, in the terminal I type (as root) `postfix start`, and I can flush queues and other stuff. It appears the postfix application is only run when needed. I however want the application to run all the time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need at least postfix running:

`sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postfix.master.plist`

The `-w` means that it will load at startup.  Otherwise it'll only run until it's stopped.

Similarly, you can undo by using `launchctl unload -w`.

Addendum: this addresses the "only runs when needed" problem Gordon indicates I missed.  Place it inside the body of the plist.

> <key>RunAtLoad</key>
>
> <true>
>
> <key>OnDemand</key>
>
> <false>

Comment: This won't help on a Mac OS X client, as the postfix launchd item already loaded by default, and is set to only activate if there's something in /var/spool/postfix/maildrop (which is the current problem).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this; I had to change "<true>" and "<false>" to "<true/>" and "<false/>" respectively to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

you have to look at launchd. 
See for example [here](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=2005050302075588).